# Using re.sub and getting error

Tags: python

I'm trying to use re.sub on a url but when I do I get a error about

```
expected string or buffer
```

This is the code:

```
elif used_prefix and cmd == "cats" and self.getAccess(user) >=1 and len(args) == 0:
   try:
      url = "http://catfacts-api.appspot.com/api/facts"
      f = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
      data = json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))["facts"]
      data = re.sub(r'\<.*?\>',"",data).replace("\\","")
      room.message("Random Cat Fact: %s" % data)
   except:
      room.message((str(sys.exc_info()[1])))
      print(traceback.format_exc())
```

It's suppose to remove the [" around the words "] and to remove the "\"aroundwords"\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))["facts"]` is a list that containing a string.

Replace following line:

```
data = json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))["facts"]
```

with:

```
data = json.loads(f.readall().decode("utf-8"))["facts"][0]
```

BTW, you don't need to escape `<`, `>`.